# Find ideal point of homogenous line

Tags: geometry

Given the line $G=(2,1,-3)$ in homogenous coordinates, how can I find the ideal point of this line?

Answer (score 0):

To get the ideal point on a given line you intersect that line with the line at infinity. Intersection is typically [calculated](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1729463/35416) as cross product and the line at infinity had coordinates $(0,0,1)$ in the conventional embedding of the plane at $z=1$.